# Parallelization slows down execution in MatLab

Tags: multithreading, matlab, parallel-processing

I am using Matlab on a Mac OS X running on a Pentium processor with 4 real cores.

I want to analyse Magnetic resonance images (MRI) and fit the signal from these images using optimisation. For every pixel I have 35 values (i.e. the same image acquired 35 times during different conditions) and I want to fit these values to some function

Below, I have stripped my code down to the very basic loop that calls the fitting function:

```
 ticid1 = tic; 

 for x= a:1:b   
 [a, b, c, d] = FitSignal(Volume(y,x,:)); 
 end;

 toc(ticid1);
```

Here `Volume` is a 3D matrix holding all MRI images about 9 MB in size. `FitSignal` thus gets an array holding 35 values for a specific pixel and the optimisation finds the best fit. The loop runs in this case 120 times (b-a = 120) which is once for every pixel that are on a horizontal line in the image.

Timing the above code using `tic` and `toc`, the entire loop takes about 50 seconds

I thought executing the code in parallel may provide some speed up. So I opened 3 workers and ran the loop with `parfor` but found only marginal (20-30%) speedup.

Then I reduced the number of workers to 1. Now running the code with `parfor` took about 90 seconds. So with 1 worker the code is app. twice as slow as when running without parallelization. This is consistent with the small benefit seen with 3 workers.

I then tried timing inside the function `FitSignal` and found that without parallelization it takes app. 0.4 seconds while with parallelization it takes 0.7 seconds.

I understand that parallelization comes with overhead but in this case it seems excessive to me. Besides, once inside the function `FitSignal`, and when there is only one worker, it should not matter if the function runs on the main process or within a worker - right ? However, running inside a sole worker, the function runs quite slower!

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? and importantly, how to change the code to take advantage of any possible speedup with parallel execution ?

Thanks in advance

PS: I have checked my system. Memory pressure low, I even issued "purge" in terminal to free memory. CPU does not exceed 15% during run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running on a single machine, Matlab automatically parallelises vector operations ([1](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95958-which-matlab-functions-benefit-from-multithreaded-computation))... except when you are running explicit parallelisation, like parfor ([2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/79428-matrix-operations-with-parallel-computing-toolbox)).

So, what is happening here is that when you run in normal, not parfor mode you are getting a 100% speedup from parallelised vector operations, based on your numbers.

When you run in parfor mode, you loose the vector operations boost, but gain the parallelisation from parfor, so half the speed of normal processing, but split over three cores, so taking about two thirds of the time.

The above is a rough estimate based on the numbers in the question; naturally for other problems these relative speedups will vary due to a number of factors, such as differing amounts of vectorized code and overheads of parfor.

Comment: Do you have any reference for matlab parallel processing workers not using vectorized operations? I have never heared that.

Comment: I was not aware of this. Searching for it now, it seems to be explained by others also here http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/79428-matrix-operations-with-parallel-computing-toolbox.

Comment: Alan: just to clarify - when you say that the parallel vector execution in normal mode has 100% speed advantage - the 100% is just an estimate based on my numbers right ? for a different scenario it could be less or it could be more ? E.g. if the code to be executed in parallel used no vectors, then normal mode would not be fast and switching to parallel mode would not be slower - correct ?

Comment: @Rozh that's a reasonable guess. But you have to also factor in overhead associated with the parallelism itself. If the loop is very short or there is a lot of communication overhead the parallel implementation might be slower. I can post an example if you like.

Comment: @Rozh yes, the numbers I stated were estimates based on your numbers.  For different scenarios the speed up would vary.  Also, thanks for the link, I've added it to the answer.

Comment: @transversality I did neglect to mention the parfor overheads, which I have now added mention to in my answer. Thanks for bringing it up.  I haven't gone into too much detail though, so feel free to do so if you think it would help.

Comment: Thanks to all. This was very helpful.